# Show block on all 404 / 403 pages only via context

Tags: blocks, 7

Without having to install even more modules on the site for context. I know there a boat load of plugins for context, but I was wondering if this can be achieved by just using core context:

I basically want to show a view block on all the 404/403 pages, which are just basic page nodes. The problem with context is when you choose path as the condition, it will only show up on that path, which is the 404/403 node paths only. Even if you put in something random like: foo.com/adsfadsf -- the context won't fire since its not a recognized path even though it is the 404 page.

What context recipe can restrict a block to show up on the error pages only? I know i can list out all the paths i dont want it to show up on, but thats not going to work in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is create a panel page for 403 and 404 page. Add whatever you want to in the panes.

Set the 403 and 404 page path under :

```
Admin > Configuration > System > Site Information
```

There is a section called `ERROR PAGES`. Add both the path there.

**Edit :**

For context use [Context Error](https://www.drupal.org/project/context_error) module.

Comment: im not using panels. im mainly using context as a replacement to panels.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: yea but i was wondering if there was a method where you didnt need to install another module.

Comment: I dont think so. Thats why this module is contributed.